# Is my this step correct?

Tags: probability

Can you please tell me whether i did correct or wrong in the following equation.

$\text{P}\left[(\sum_{k=1}^{M}V_k)<x\right]$

=
$\left[\sum_{k=1}^{M}\text{P}(V_k<x)\right]$-------(1)

where $\text{P}$ is probability, $V_k$ is random variables.

Is my step in eq.(1) correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly wrong. Suppose that $M=2$, $x=1$, and each $V_k$ is $0$ or $1$, each with probability $\frac12$. Then the lefthand side is $\frac14$, and the righthand side is $\frac12+\frac12=1$.

Comment: Ok.....can you please tell how to solve it.

Comment: @Pranu: I’m afraid that I don’t have enough context, and it’s not really in my field anyway.